# How to check the position of similar elements in a vector

Tags: r

I have a vector like this:

```
firstChar=c("a","b","c","b","b","d","c")
```

I need to know the position of the similar element in vector, for example some thing like [2,4,5] and [3,7]. What function can do it simply.

Comment: are you looking for identity or similarity of the values? If the latter, could you expand upon your definition of similarity, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the base function `which` for this:

```
which(firstChar == "a")
> [1] 1

which(firstChar == "b")
> [1] 2 4 5

which(firstChar == "c")
> [1] 3 7
```

Answer (score 1):

For every unique value

```
> for (i in unique(firstChar)) {
>   cat(i,which(firstChar==i),"\n")
> }

a 1 
b 2 4 5 
c 3 7 
d 6
```